# firewall is enable but gufw wont lauch

Tags: firewall, ufw, gufw

The firewall is enabled. But I can't launch `gufw` interface.

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active
```

Comment: sudo gufw status
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/gufw/gufw/gufw.py", line 21, in <module>
    from gufw.view.gufw  import Gufw
  File "/usr/share/gufw/gufw/gufw/view/gufw.py", line 18, in <module>
    import gi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'